# Can I specify a separate activation email?

Tags: email, activation

I have a general sign up page, and special sign up page that assigns those sign ups to a different group.

Is there a way to send general the normal activation email, and my special group a differently worded activation email?

Thanks!

Comment: what plugin do you use for sign up page?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with [Postmaster](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster).